# inlay or composite image into corner of larger image, GraphicsMagic or ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, animation, graphicsmagick, compositing

(A) I have a rotation of a part so I have 360 tiff files, which I can animate in ImageMagick and also export to an animated gif.  This image is  1920x1080, with a black background, there are 360 of them: `image_A_001.tiff` to `image_A_360.tiff`.

(B) I have a close up of the rotation that I want to inlay (composite?) into the each of the 360 images files from (A).  This closeup image can be around 200x200 in size, also has a black background.  There are 360 of these as well, `image_B_001.tiff` to `image_B_360.tiff`, and they correspond to each image_A_###.tiff.

I would like to inlay image_B_001.tiff into image_A_001.tiff into the upper right hand corner, `creating image_C_001.tiff` and do this for each of the 360 files, then convert those new 360 image files to an animated gif.  Can ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick in linux do this, and if so how?  Otherwise how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ImageMagick tool you are looking for is
[composite](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/composite.html),
whose syntax is :

```
composite [ options ... ] image composite [ mask ] composited
```

If I understood right, *image* is `image_A_001.tiff`,
*composite* is `image_B_001.tiff`,
and *composited* is `image_C_001.tiff`.

The most important option to specify is where the inlay should be positioned,
specified by
[-gravity](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/ImageMagick.html#details-gravity).

Comment: thank you.  here's what worked `gm composite smaller_image_001.tif -gravity NorthEast larger_image_001.tif new_image.tif`

Comment: also `gm composite smaller_image_001.tif -geometry +1500+100 larger_image_001.tif new_image.tif` puts in general northeast location but allows placement of smaller image to my liking

Comment: I made use of *GraphicsMagick* via `gm`